# Moving all base class definition to a common dll

Tags: c#, architecture, mef

I am using MEF in my application. My application have 4 parts(class library) and a main module , the main modules responsibility is to interact with the above said parts and delegates job to them.

I have coded all the interface and abstract base classes in a library called 'Common' and refer it to all the other dlls which have classes inherit from those base classes. I moved all the base class and interface definition to the 'Common' library so that i can add reference of that dll in my main program and all the base classes and interfaces are readily available.

Is this the right way to do it? What is the other option in MEF using which i can refer to the base classes in my main module without referring to a dll.

eg:-  abstract class baseAbc and interface IAbc is defined in common.dll, Is it possible to refer baseAbc and IAbc in my main module without adding reference to Common.dll

Comment: Have you posted this question on CodeProject as well, or is someone trying to game the system? http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4440741/A-MEF-question.aspx

Comment: Yes i have posted it in Code Project as well.